# Bokeh RangeSlider not honoring step size

Tags: python, bokeh

*I have a step size of 100 but the slider moves in increments of 300.*

*I am using bokeh==1.0.2*

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, gridplot, column
from bokeh.models.widgets import RangeSlider
from bokeh.models import Panel

output_file("range_slider.html")

range_slider = RangeSlider(start=-100, end=70000, value=(-100,70000), step=100, title="Stuff")


controls = widgetbox(range_slider)


show(controls)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine with Bokeh v1.1.0 if you specify an appropriate slider width e.g. `width = 701`.

The truth is that the **actual step value** depends on the **slider bar pixel width** value.

If you want the slider matches exactly your step size you need to ensure the slider width in pixels equals the range value divided by the step size.

Please note that you don't specify the slider width which in Bokeh v1.1.0 defaults to 300 pixels. For a range `start=-100, end=70000` and a `step = 100` this means **701 different values** that must be mapped to **300 points**. This results in a value of 233 per 1 pixel which Bokeh rounds up to 200 or 300 per step to preserve the correct values mapping and to match the start/end values.

So two sliders with exactly the same start/end/step values will have different actual step value dependent on the slider `width`

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import Column, RangeSlider

range_slider1 = RangeSlider(start=-100, end=70000, value=(-100,70000), step=100, title="Stuff", width = 701)
range_slider2 = RangeSlider(start=-100, end=70000, value=(-100,70000), step=100, title="Stuff", width = 300)

controls = Column(range_slider1, range_slider2)

show(controls)
```

Comment: Thank You you for explaining that to me.